# AUTO INCREMENT concurrency issue and ordering

Tags: mysql-5.6, locking, transaction, concurrency, auto-increment

Let's suppose that table t1 has an `AUTO INCREMENT` primary key `id`. And let's say that I am starting two transactions at different moments of time, and that transactions are started by the same application code. Long running select has different time duration, so it can take more or less time, unpredictable.

```
Session 1                    Session 2
start transaction;          
(long running select)
                             start transaction;
                             (long running select)
                             insert into t ...
insert into t ...            commit;
commit;
```

From this point, if I do `select * from t` I would see that `AUTO INCREMENT` field `id` value related to Session 1 is bigger than value related to Session 2, thus reversing order of connections.

**How to prevent that?**

Here is the real showcase:

```
> CREATE TABLE t ( c1 INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, c2 VARCHAR, PRIMARY KEY (c1) ) ENGINE = InnoDB;


Session 1                               Session 2
start transaction;          
                                        start transaction;
                                        insert into t values('2nd transaction')
insert into t values('1st transaction') commit;
commit;

> SELECT * FROM t;
+----+--------------------+
| c1 | c2                 |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 |    2nd transaction |
|  2 |    1st transaction |
+----+--------------------+
```

What I really need is some locking mechanism, so it would look like this:

```
Session 1                               Session 2
start transaction;
** some locking **          
                                        start transaction;
                                        ** some locking **
                                        insert into t values('2nd transaction')
                                        ** wait for lock releasing **
insert into t values('1st transaction') 
commit;
                                        ** lock released **
                                        commit;


> SELECT * FROM t;
+----+--------------------+
| c1 | c2                 |
+----+--------------------+
|  1 |    1st transaction |
|  2 |    2nd transaction |
+----+--------------------+
```

If I do `LOCK TABLES t WRITE` as soon as transactions are started, that solves the issue, but creates another one, related to metadata locking from other transactions, like this:

```
Session 1                               Session 2
start transaction;
select * from t;          
                                        start transaction;
                                        lock tables t write;
                                        ** hangs, waiting for metadata lock releasing **


commit;
                                        ** metadata lock on t released **
                                        <next statements>
                                        commit;
```

and this is creating serious issues when doing backup with `mysqldump --single-transaction`

Regarding the suggestion to change the application logic to not use `id` values in this way, and add a `timestamp` column in the table and use that instead:

The developers informed me that table in question serves as queue. That's why the order is important. Would moving it to some more MQ related technologies (like RabbitMQ, or even redis) be worth it?

Comment: I suggest you change the application logic to not use id values in such way. Add a timestamp column in the table and use that instead. The value can be the transaction start time (record it in a variable when the transaction starts, use it later in the inserts). Leave the id alones ;)

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ, I totally agree with that proposal. Explicit locking is just a source of trouble. But it's not up to me to make final decision. That assumes extra effort from developers, which means extra investments, extra time, etc, etc, and that goes to business logic.

Comment: Sadly, almost any solution would require some sort of additional development effort. If the key is for development effort an time to not be spent on changing how the items are selected and instead on changing the database transaction side so that IDs represent an ordering by transaction start time, then consider not using an auto-increment key. Is there a requirement that the IDs be sequential? If not, then create a process that provides a next ID in a very short independent transaction immediately before actually starting the transaction to save the date. If it doesn't get save, the ID's lost